# Unable to dequeue a custom cell with identifier while the TableViewController is launched programmatically from the AppDelegate

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

In my appDelegate class, I've created a UITabController where I'm adding 4 tableViewControllers as items of the tabBarController. The goal is to have 4 items that use a single version of the tableViewController.

Here is the portion of the code that setups the tableView controllers and add them to the tabBar controller

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)

    let controller1 = setUpViewControllers(title: "Item 1")
    let controller2 = setUpViewControllers(title: "Item 2")
    let controller3 = setUpViewControllers(title: "Item 3")
    let controller4  = setUpViewControllers(title: "Item 4")

    // Set up the tab bar controller
    let tabController = UITabBarController()
    tabController.setViewControllers([controller1,controller2,controller3,controller4], animated: true)

    // use the tab bar controller as the root view controller
    window?.rootViewController = tabController
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

    return true
}
```

And the following is the definition of the function that creates the tableView controller

```
func setUpViewControllers(title : String) -> MyTableViewController {

    let vc =  MyTableViewController();
    vc.tabBarItem.title = title

    return vc
}
```

in my tableView controller,

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let model = listOfData[indexPath.row]

    let currentRow = indexPath.row

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellIdentifier", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell


     // the error starts when the code reaches this part, the properties of the cell:
     // title and details are nil
     cell.title.text = model.title
     cell.details.text = model.details

     return cell
 }
```

The cell used in the above code, it's a cell that I designed in the storyboard and linked its view to a subclass of UITableViewCell

```
import UIKit

class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var title: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var details: UILabel!
}
```

At first when I launched the app, I had the following exception

```
NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier cellIdentifier - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'
```

I tried to do what the exception's message said, I registered my custom cell in viewDidLoad() of my tableView controller

```
self.tableView.register(CustomCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cellIdentifier")
```

And this time, the exception is gone but I cannot access my cell's views as they are all nil. 
I can't figure out why it's not working.

Comment: Did you check that `CustomCell` has it's `reuseIdentifier` set to "cellIdentifier"?

Comment: Have you designed `MyTableView` and a prototype `CustomCell` in your Storyboard?

Comment: @DonMag yes, both MyTableView and Custom Cell were designed in storyboard

Comment: @wilc0, yes I've already set it from the storyboard

Comment: You **must not** register a cell if it's a prototype cell designed in a storyboard. Check if the class and the identifier (this is **not** the Restoration ID) of the cell is set properly in Interface Builder as already mentioned in the very first comment..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not instantiating `MyTableViewController` from you're storyboard... you're simply creating instances of the class.

Your `setUpViewControllers` func needs to look (about) like this:

```
func setUpViewControllers(title : String) -> MyTableViewController {

    let storyboardName = "Main"
    let controllerID = "MyTableViewController"

    let sb = UIStoryboard(name: storyboardName, bundle: nil)
    guard let vc = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: controllerID) as? MyTableViewController else {
        fatalError("Couldn't instantiate MyTableViewController")
    }
    vc.tabBarItem.title = title
    return vc

}
```

If the controller is in a storyboard other than "Main" then change it accordingly, as well as the StoryboardID of your controller.

**EDIT** - then you also should not need the `self.tableView.register(CustomCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cellIdentifier")` line.